# Can I install Ubuntu, and Boot into it without changing Booting method

Tags: boot, laptop, lenovo

Hi I have a 15ARR with ryzen 3 and Vega graphics. I am trying to install Linux, but I can't make it to boot from the USB. I tried with the Novo button, it shows me the screen that would allow me to enter to Bios setup and Boot options but as soon as I select something and press enter, it boots windows, it never shows me Bios Setup or anything.

I googled and can't find anything in the lenovo forums

Please help this is getting frustrating

Comment: No, you cannot. You need to ask support from your BIOS or Mainboard manufacturer or maybe someone at [Super User](https://superuser.com/) might be able to help.

Comment: Is that a Lenovo model? Have you updated UEFI from Lenovo?  If SSD update firmware also. Make sure your flash drive installer is correct. Some just have issues with some brands of flash drives or port on system. Some Lenovo have a locked boot order which you need to change. Is UEFI Secure Boot off?